# exec format error when building docker image from arm32v7 golang image

Tags: linux, docker, go, arm, alpine-linux

I am trying to build a docker image FROM `arm32v7/golang:1.13.4-alpine` which I was successfully build from a mac but when I try to build it on a linux machine, it throws an `exec format error`.
There so many questions on `exec format error` but couldn't find any solution.
My docker file looks like below

```
FROM arm32v7/golang:1.13.4-alpine as staging

RUN .....
RUN .....
RUN tar -czvf sbuild.tar.gz ./servicebuild
......
......
CMD tar -xzvf sbuild.tar.gz && ./servicebuild
```

It basically fails at the first command in the docker file throwing an error
`standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

Architecture of the build machine
`Linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Is arm32v7 not supported on the above architecture? Is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: as per the name arm32xxxxxx  its for computers running an ARM cpu which is a different architecture from x86_64  ... beauty of golang is there are alpine golang docker images for most architectures ... on your linux box try putting following at top of your Dockerfile  `ARG GO_VERSION=1.14`  followed by next line `FROM golang:${GO_VERSION}-alpine AS staging`  of course if the balance of lines of Dockerfile pull in architecture specific code you will need to amend those too

Comment: I did try this and this works fine as long as I dont compress the go build to a tar file. But when I compress the go build to reduce the size, image builds but doesnt run on arm32 machine. I have added script for archiving in the question

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable execution of different multi-architecture containers by QEMU  and binfmt_misc.

In recent distro this can be simply done by running:

```
apt-get install qemu-user-static
```

If this doesn't work for you, you can execute :

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset --persistent yes --credential yes
```

Note that this may reconfigure any existing binfmt_misc setup that you have. See https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static for more detail.

This information is available in one alpine repositories README but not on the wiki as far as I know : https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/docker-abuild#configure-multi-arch-support

Answer (score 0):

It's because Docker for Mac supports multi-CPU architecture: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/

As far as I know, on Linux using native Docker you don't have that. Although you might be able to do it by installing extra software. Checkout this post for example: https://medium.com/@artur.klauser/building-multi-architecture-docker-images-with-buildx-27d80f7e2408